# Применение хоков в рендер методе

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Всем привет. Я тут перечитывал документауию реакта и нашел там кое-что интересное, касательно использования хоков в рендер методах компонентов. И тут я вспомнил, что у меня есть как раз такой) В общем, можете, пожалуйста, объяснить есть ли тут ошибка и как ее, если что, решить.

Тут я использую хоки для дополнительной кастомизации компоненты. В AppRouter я передаю массив объектов-путей с различными настройками. И вот в зависимости от этих настроек применяю хоки. В общем, насколько так вообще правильно делать?

```
const AppRouter = ({routes, redirectPath = '/', fallbackElement}) => {
const getRoute = (path, exact, component) => <Route key={path} exact={exact} path={path} component={component}/>;

return (
    <Switch>
        {routes.map(route => {
            let component = route.Component;

            if (route.lazyLoading) component = withSuspense(component, fallbackElement);
            if (route.withAuth) component = withAuthRedirect(component);

            return getRoute(route.path, route.exact, component);
        })}

        <Redirect to={redirectPath}/>
    </Switch>
);};
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI4oA.jpg

Comment: Наверное не хоки, а ловушки, хуки (англ. hook)?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Нет, все таки хоки(hoc - higher order component) - компоненты высшего порядка.

Comment: А, теперь яснее. По-моему, надо "кэшировать" обернутые компоненты, то есть создавать каждый только однократно (при первой потребности), а далее переиспользовать созданные ранее. И в теории, это позволит реакту выполнять те малые оптимизации, на которые он способен. Возможно, с реализацией поможет `Map`, в роли "словаря псевдосинглтонов компонентов", где ключами могут быть сериализованные в строку/битмаск наборы свойств роута (для генерации ключей применять хелпер-функцию). Но я в реакте плохо понимаю (сам Vue-разраб), и мог написать чушь - относись к предложенной идее максимально критически.

Comment: Возможно, я уже сделал что-то похожее при помощи memo(). Не уверен, что это то самое, но пусть будет. В целом, все работает нормально, просто я начал беспокоиться из-за этого, вот и задал вопрос

Comment: Если эта функция в коде вопроса вызывается только однократно, то ничего делать не нужно, все прекрасно. Если же она может вызываться несколько раз (каждый раз конструируя новые экземпляры компонентов), то проблема действительно есть, т.к. (насколько знаю) реакт не умеет определять изменения подобно другим библиотекам реактивности (реализующим "глубокое" сравнение изменений в Shadow DOM, и обновляющих только измененную часть дерева).

Comment: Ну, рендер произошел всего 1 раз. Я рад) Спасибо, что успокоили)